# How to expand jwt time? Jwt version : "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0-rc.2" Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, token

How to extend the duration of the token ? I have function with expired time but not work correctly.

```
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 464465353454316000,
            'user' => auth()->user()
        ]);
    }
}
```

The token expires very quickly.

```
'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 464465353454316000 //this line not work property. Token expired early
```

Comment: Egad, where are you getting this number from?

Comment: I set manual. But default is *60

Comment: Don't you get int overflow in this situation? Why not simply `'expires_in' => 60 * 60 * 24 * 7// 1 week`?

Comment: @Justinas This will work? 
'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 
?

Comment: `auth()->factory()->getTTL()` presumably returns the number of minutes the token should work for, and the `* 60` converts that to seconds. What's the value of `auth()->factory()->getTTL()` in your case?

Comment: the max integer size on 32 bit is 147483647, maybe there lies (a part of) your problem

Comment: @Thomas I set  'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60 * 60 * 24 * 17 
That will be 17 weeks and  in response "expires_in": 88128000, 
Is this okey?

Comment: No, internally the integer is still overflowing possibly. Just writing it down as a multiplication will not help. Maybe you can try first with a hardcoded value less than the max integer and see if it works then, to rule out that that is the problem.

Comment: Problem with this version of jwt is because i don't have jwt file in config folder and I can't edit it is config folder. Question is simple, how I can expand time token?

Comment: @AlexAl Did you try to [publish the config folder](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/laravel-installation/)? `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"`

Comment: @cbaconnier That is problem 
I need set in config/jwt 
'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', TIME),

Comment: I don't get what your problem is. `config/jwt.php`  [is available](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/1.0.0-rc.2/src/Providers/LaravelServiceProvider.php#L23) on 1.0.0-rc.2 Once you **publish** the file, you can [set your TTL](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/1.0.0-rc.2/config/config.php#L103)

Comment: Now is everythink good 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Publish the config file on your terminal `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"`
Open `config/jwt.php` set `ttl` to minutes you want, the default is 60 min.

Comment: Yes that is true. @cbaconnier is give answear on my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It works for me:

```
use JWTAuth;
...
            'expires_in' => JWTAuth::factory()->getTTL() * 24,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTTL to set token expires not getTTL().
getTTL function only shows how long the token expires in minutes

```
$token = auth()->setTTL(1440)->attempt($credentials);
//If you do this, your token will be valid for 1 day

protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL(),
            'user' => auth()->user()
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60000
```

If you do this, your token will be valid for 1 day